# Java: printing to file when you can't use "throw exception"

Tags: java, io

I have a class for threads (implements runnable). I want to be able to print text to a file inside the method "run", but I can't add "throws IOException" because run() is an implementation of a method in runnable.

Of course there's no way I'll use a gazillion "Try-Catch" in run()...

Thanks

Comment: Why not use Try-Catch inside a run?  You'd need to be able to handle errors inside a run() in the first place, anyway.

Comment: i have lots of things to print, it seems like a terrible lot of try-catch. I really enjoy Java, but I was hoping for a C-like "you better know what you're doing" approach to file IO. Is there a way to force Java to compile in this case ?

Comment: you only need 1 try catch block.

Comment: Even if you could get Java to compile the source code, the JVM wouldn't run it.

Comment: I can wrap the ENTIRE code inside the run() method in a try-catch ?

Comment: yes. If one write fails, there's no point trying to write more stuff, the file is invalid. so put everything in the run method inside a try block.

Comment: If you put the *whole* `run` method then the whole method will exit as soon as *any* of the writes fail. If you'll never have a write fail or any of your writes failing should be fatal, then you could do this.

Comment: @Gabe - *"Even if you could get Java to compile the source code, the JVM wouldn't run it."*.  Actually, that is false.  The JVM will happily execute code that throws checked exceptions that have not been declared.

Comment: @Gabe, if one write fails what's the likelyhood of any of the other succeeding? Second, The file is invalid as it is not in the format you intended it to be because part of it is missing. 1 try catch block is absolutely the right approach.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: If the whole point of the method is just to write a text file, he could put it all in a string buffer and write it all at once. I assumed he was logging to a file, in which case maybe it doesn't matter if the write fails and he wants to continue his operation without logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dealing with checked exceptions in your `run()` method is tricky for the following reasons:

1. As @kenson john says (and you observed) you can't simply let them propagate, because `run()` is not declared as throwing checked exceptions.
2. If you catch them and rethrow them wrapped in unchecked exceptions, they are likely to go unnoticed by the `main` thread.  Why?  Because the exceptions are thrown on the stack of the child thread.  Unless they are caught in the `run()` method, they will be dealt with by the thread's [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) object ... which is likely to be the default handler ... which writes a stacktrace to `System.err` and then discards the exception.
3. Now you can set another `UncaughtExceptionHandler` object for the child thread, or even set a default `UncaughtExceptionHandler` for the JVM.  But what should the handler  do?  Ideally, the exception needs to be reported back to the `main` thread (or whatever) to take executive action.  But there's no way that the child thread, or a handler for that thread can throw an exception on the main thread's stack.  (The best you could do to get the main thread's attention would be to set a flag or call `Thread.interrupt()` on the main thread ... and hope that it checks the flag / interrupt status periodically.)
4. Any `IOException` that is thrown while writing to an output file indicates that something serious has gone wrong; e.g. the file system is full, or the socket or pipe you were writing to is broken / closed.  So simply ignoring it **could be** a big mistake.  (For instance, suppose that the file is precious, and that the last thing that the application does is to delete the old version of the file and replace it with the new version we just created.  Ooops!  We didn't notice that the FS filled up, the new version of the file is corrupt and we just deleted the old version.)

In the light of this, the `PrintStream` approach is simplest.  A `PrintStream` will quietly catch any `IOException` that occurs while writing, but record the fact that an exception has occurred.  So when the `main` thread decides that everything should have finished writing, it needs to call [`PrintStream.checkError()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#checkError%28%29) to test if any errors have occurred.  (Unfortunately, the API does not allow you to find out what the actual exception was.)

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the output with a `PrintStream`, it never throws exceptions.

Comment: +1 - though depending on the application, it may be *advisable* to check that there have been no errors when / after closing the PrintStream.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a particular I/O operation in many places without putting each one in an exception handler, just create a function with an exception handler (i.e. it doesn't throw). Then call the non-throwing function to do all your I/O.

Answer (score 1):

I understand why you want to do this, but I think it is a bad practice to throw and catch an exception from run()  (which is impossible for the reason mentioned below).

An exception generated from run() would be considered as an "Unchecked" exception in Java. This kind of exception should not be caught by the programmer, and should be taken care of by the VM.

Unchecked exception generally happen at runtime, example: NullPointerException, IllegalStateException.

IOException being a subclass of java.lang.Exception is considered a Checked Exception, therefore should be handled using a try catch within run() or in a method invoked by run().